# Programming for multiple monitors

Tags: .net, multiple-monitors, monitors

I'm currrently working as a junior consultant at some company and there **trying** to make an app that runs on tree screens simultaneously does anyone have a clue on where to start at something like this, maybe a design pattern or some awesome lib.
Any help would be great.

- a single running app thats runs across tree monitors each screen would be responsible for a windows form or multiple forms.
- right now where in the technical analysis of the thing

Comment: It depends what you want to do with that monitors! Simply place windows there? Drawing full-screen graphics?

Comment: I would actually be quite interested to know how to do this in an XNA context. Has anyone got experience with that?

Comment: 3 forms or 1 form which is ultra-wide?

Answer (score 3):

It is really rather simple, you just need to set the form's Location property so it is displayed on another monitor.  Best done with the Load() event, using the Screen class to find out where the other monitors are located.  For example:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        // Display on 2nd monitor, if available
        if (Screen.AllScreens.Length >= 2) {
            this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
        }
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

If it is your intention to display *one* window across multiple monitors (it isn't clear from the question): no, Winforms won't let you do this.  Raymond Chen just recently [blogged about](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/03/05/10277439.aspx)  the kind of trouble that causes.

Comment: From that Raymond Chen blog post, it sounds like it IS possible, it's just not standard windows behavior. Fair enough, but then, anyone have any idea how to do it. When I try and set the SIZE of a form to bigger than the screen I'm positioning it on, it immediately snaps to the single screen's size.

Comment: Right, Raymond channeled Winforms behavior without blogging about it.

Comment: Very strange but it looks like the behavior has something to do with being in the VS IDE. When I run the app in the IDE, form sizes basically snap to the size of the screen the IDE is on. But when I compile and run the exe itself, the form can be sized arbitrarily large, even across the entire virtual screen. Oh well, at least now I know.